# Logic App deployment from Visual Studio 2017 fails

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-logic-apps, gateway

I have created a Logic App in Azure which works fine in Azure itself. So I first recreated the Logic App within VS2017 (with "Azure Logic Apps for Visual Studio" extension installed). The logic app contains a trigger to read from the Azure Servicebus and calls a custom logic app connector action. This custom connector calls a SOAP webservice via an Azure Data Gateway, which runs fine.

Now the issue is that when I try to deploy it from VS2017, it complains in the Output window. The message I get is:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 13:41:34 - Resource MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS 'MyCustomConnector' failed with message '{"error": {"code": "ConnectionGatewayFailure","message": "Establishing connection with the service failed with code 'BadRequest'."}}'
```

My Logic App works great because I receive the SOAP request in my on-premise application.

What I have tried so far:

- Checked my permissions, I am now owner of the resource groups (one where the Logic App and custom connector resides in, and one where the Gateway resides in)
- Copied content in: "My resource group > Settings > Automation script > Json Template" and pasted it into Visual Studio
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Added "-DeploymentDebugLogLevel All" to my Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 file, doesn't show me anything more useful.
- [Troubleshoot common Azure deployment errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors) which says for BadRequest: "You sent deployment values that do not match what is expected by Resource Manager. Check the inner status message for help with troubleshooting." I see no inner status message.
- Checked Google for a useful answer

But up until now, without success. So hopefully some of you can help me.

Edit: Here's my ARM template, I renamed a few things, hopefully not too much.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "connections_servicebus_name": {
            "defaultValue": "servicebus",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "customApis_MyCustomConnector_name": {
            "defaultValue": "My-Custom-Connector",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "connections_MyCustomConnector_name": {
            "defaultValue": "My-Custom-Connector",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "workflows_MyLogicApp_name": {
            "defaultValue": "My-LogicApp",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "workflows_MyLogicApp_id": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/My-Integration-Account",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup-B/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/My-LogicApp'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_MyLogicApp_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "tags": {},
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "integrationAccount": {
                    "id": "[parameters('workflows_MyLogicApp_id')]"
                },
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {
                        "$connections": {
                            "defaultValue": {},
                            "type": "Object"
                        }
                    },
                    "triggers": {
                        
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        
                    },
                    "outputs": {}
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                        "value": {
                            "My-Custom-Connector": {
                                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_MyCustomConnector_name'))]",
                                "connectionName": "My-Custom-Connector",
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name'))]"
                            },
                            "servicebus": {
                                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_servicebus_name'))]",
                                "connectionName": "servicebus",
                                "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/servicebus"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_MyCustomConnector_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('connections_servicebus_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup-B/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/My-Custom-Connector'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_MyCustomConnector_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "LogicAppsCustomConnector-Connection",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/customApis', parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup-B/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
            "name": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "worker_outbound",
                "customParameterValues": {},
                "api": {
                    "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/', parameters('connections_servicebus_name'))]"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        },
        {
            "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup-B/providers/Microsoft.Web/customApis/My-Custom-Connector'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/customApis",
            "name": "[parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "scale": null,
            "properties": {
                "connectionParameters": {
                    "authType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "allowedValues": [
                            {
                                "value": "none"
                            }
                        ],
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "displayName": "Authentication Type",
                            "description": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                            "tooltip": "Authentication type to connect to your API",
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 1,
                                "required": "true",
                                "allowedValues": [
                                    {
                                        "text": "none",
                                        "value": "anonymous"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "capability": [
                                    "gateway"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "gateway": {
                        "type": "gatewaySetting",
                        "gatewaySettings": {
                            "dataSourceType": "CustomConnector",
                            "connectionDetails": []
                        },
                        "uiDefinition": {
                            "constraints": {
                                "tabIndex": 4,
                                "required": "true",
                                "capability": [
                                    "gateway"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "brandColor": "#ffffff",
                "description": "Calls My SOAP test webservice.",
                "displayName": "[parameters('customApis_MyCustomConnector_name')]",
                "iconUri": 
            },
            "dependsOn": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The deployment of your custom connector failed. could you share your ARM template please ?

Comment: I've added the ARM templated as you asked Thomas.

Comment: when you connect your logic app to your custom connector (from the portal) do you have to authenticate, specify any creds ??

Comment: I created a Logic App Custom Connector, chose SOAP (Preview) and Call mode: SOAP pass-through. Next in the general information I checked the Connect via on-premises data gateway, and that's it, no further authentication whatsoever. Also when using it, I only provide it a SOAP envelope. The only thing I have to provide is the connection to the gateway on the action itself, perhaps it cannot connect to it via Visual Studio? But how can I resolve that if it works in Azure?

Comment: @VincentVerweij Did you find the solution? I'm stuck with the same issue and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ShivRajawat, I still don't know what actual solution was. What helped me though was the Resource Explorer in the Azure Portal. I tried to get a grasp of the JSON structure and created it from scratch without the designer and in Visual Studio 2017. After that it suddenly worked. One important thing when using the Custom LogicApp Connector for SOAP (like I did) in your LogicApp is, do not forget to add the following in the input: `"headers": { "Content-Type": "text/xml", "SOAPAction": "http://tempuri.org/" }`, that might also cause a BadRequest... Hope this helps.